# function being called n+1 times instead of once -- why?

Tags: jquery, facebook

In jquery, I have an event for when you click an element called quote_box on my page. If you click quote_box, a popup comes up. One of things on the popup is a Facebook icon. If you click the Facebook icon, you go to a different event. The idea is that each quote box represents a different person. If you click a person's quote box, then what gets sent to Facebook is a URL with the name of the person on the end of it.

What happens is that the first time you click a quote box then click the Facebook icon, the Facebook function is called once. You close the popup and click another quote box then click the Facebook icon again. The Facebook function is called twice. You close the popup and click another quote box and then click the Facebook icon again. The Facebook function is called three times, etc.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here is my code:

html:

```
    <section class="container">
      <div class="one-fourth" id="Abby">
        <div class="quote_box">
            <div class="person_name quote">Abby McCracken</div>
            <div class="attribution"><span class="person_age">18,</span> <span class="person_where">Greater Latrobe Senior High School</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile_attribution"><span class="bold">Abby McCracken, 18</span><br/>Greater Latrobe</div>
      </div>
      <div class="one-fourth" id="Ahjani">
        <div class="quote_box">
                <div class="person_name quote">Ahjani Williams</div>
                <div class="attribution"><span class="person_age">17,</span> <span class="person_where">Aliquippa Senior High School</span></div>
        </div>
    ...
</section>

<div id="popup_player">
    <div id="popup_social">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook videoFBlink" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>

    <video id="person_video" controls playsinline poster="img/mobile_video_still.jpg">

    </video>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.quote_box').on('tap', function() {
        $('.mask').fadeIn();
        //get video file name
        thisID = $(this).parent().attr('id');

        //if click facebook icon for this video 
        $('.videoFBlink').on('tap', function() {
            posttoFB(thisID);
            return false;
        });


    });
function posttoFB(shareFile) {
        console.log(shareFile);
        if (shareFile !== undefined) {
            var shareurl = "https://mywebsite?file=" + shareFile;
        } else {
            var shareurl = "https://nmywebsite";
        }
        window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+escape(shareurl)+'&t='+window.location, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you set multiple "tap" events (the one inside is doubled)

```
$('.quote_box').on('tap', function() {
    $('.mask').fadeIn();
    //get video file name
    thisID = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    //if click facebook icon for this video 
    $('.videoFBlink').off("tap").on('tap', function() {
        posttoFB(thisID);
        return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it! I'll mark  this as the answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested event handler. You created an event that is triggering the creation of another event. You can create an event handler without the object currently being displayed. I recommend un-nesting the events like this:

```
     var currentID = 0;

        $('.quote_box').on('tap', function() {
            $('.mask').fadeIn();
            //get video file name
            currentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        });

     //if click facebook icon for this video 
            $('.videoFBlink').on('tap', function() {
                posttoFB(currentID );
                return false;
            });

    function posttoFB(shareFile) {
            console.log(shareFile);
            if (shareFile !== undefined) {
                var shareurl = "https://mywebsite?file=" + shareFile;
            } else {
                var shareurl = "https://nmywebsite";
            }
            window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+escape(shareurl)+'&t='+window.location, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600'); 
        }
```